# What is the purpose of JPA EntityTransaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, transactions

I've noticed some guys use EntityTransaction to persist entities. I've never used it and I'm not sure why and in which situations this approach may be needed. Simply calling a persist method on the EntityManager does the trick as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [`EntityTransaction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityTransaction.html) is used for programmatic transaction management.

If you are using Spring or Java EE, then you are most likely using declarative transaction boundaries.

In that case, you're only responsibility is to properly annotate the Service methods with [`@Transactional`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) and the Spring/Java EE container will begin/commit/rollback the transaction on your behalf.